# no match for vector operator using cout

Tags: c++, cout

I wrote a program which is supposed to just print all the strings in a vector.
I'm using an Iterator.
The error I'm getting is:

```
no match for 'operator[]' in '((Students*)this)->Students::courses_[it]'
```

This is my code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include "../include/Courses.h"
class Courses;

class Students {
private:
string name_;
int id_;

public:
vector<string> courses_;
void print_courses(){
    vector<string>::iterator it;
    for(it=courses_.begin();it < courses_.end(); it++)
            cout << this->courses_[it] << " ";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An iterator is used by dereferncing it, not by feeding it to operator[]. Your code should be:

```
void print_courses(){
    vector<string>::iterator it;
    for(it=courses_.begin();it < courses_.end(); it++)
            cout << *it << " ";
}
```

operator[] is used to index a vector by numbers.

Answer (score 4):

The iterator points to the elements of the vector, you don't use it to index into the vector.

```
for(it=courses_.begin();it < courses_.end(); it++) {
  cout << *it << " ";
}
```

If you have a C++11 compiler that supports range based `for` loops, the loop can be made a little more succinct

```
for( auto const& c : courses ) {
  cout << c << " ";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You want to say: `cout << *it << " ";`

Answer (score 3):

"it" is an iterator, not an index.
You need to change the line to -

```
cout << *it <<" " ;
```

Or else loop through the indices like this -

```
for(int it=0; courses_.size(); ++it)
        cout << this->courses_[it] << " ";
```

You can't mix the two approaches

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean:

```
cout << (*it) << " ";
```

Answer (score 1):

This is completely wrong. Change the line:

```
cout << this->courses_[it] << " ";
```

to :

```
cout << *it << " ";
```

Or, change the whole for loop to:

```
for(vector<string>::size_type i=0; i<courses_.size(); ++i) {
  cout << this->courses_[i] << " ";
}
```